# Test isolation in async pytest fixtures for SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pytest, python-asyncio

Running a Pytest suite with asyncio and SQLAlchemy I don't know how to fix the problem.

My pytest conftest.py is set up as follows:

```py
# conftest.py

DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql+asyncpg://user:pass@host:5432/db'

async_engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, echo=True)
AsyncSessionLocal = async_sessionmaker(
    bind=async_engine,
    class_=AsyncSession,
    autocommit=False,
    autoflush=False,
    expire_on_commit=False,
)

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def event_loop(request) -> asyncio.AbstractEventLoop:
    # making the event loop accessible in the session
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
async def create_test_database():
    # setup and teardown of database
    async with async_engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
    yield
    async with async_engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
async def db() -> AsyncSession:
    # yield a database session used by test functions
    async with AsyncSessionLocal() as session:
        yield session
```

If I run my ~200 tests like this they fail due to non-existent test isolation ( `test_function2(db)` accesses something that `test_function1(db)` has set up previously, so the assertion fails).

### Option 1: Set up and teardown in each function:

Change the fixture scope of `create_test_database` to run in every function:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
async def create_test_database():
```

This leads to very long test runs, seemingly exponential.

### Option 2: Truncate

Adding this fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
async def truncate_tables():
    async with async_engine.begin() as conn:
        for table in reversed(Base.metadata.sorted_tables):
            await conn.execute(table.delete())
    yield
```

... truncates the tables after each test function. This runs fine but it smells like a hack. Is there a better way?

My deps:

```
aiosqlite==0.19.0
alembic==1.11.2
anyio==3.7.1
asyncpg==0.27.0
fastapi==0.97.0
pytest==7.4.0
pytest-asyncio==0.21.1
SQLAlchemy==2.0.19
```

Is there a better option to achieve test isolation via pytest fixtures in SQLAlchemy using Async?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't combine `create_test_database()` to `db()`:

```py
# client.py
async def create_tables():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(models.Base.metadata.create_all)

async def drop_tables():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(models.Base.metadata.drop_all)

#conftest.py
@pytest.fixture
async def db() -> AsyncSession:
    async with async_session() as session:
        await create_tables()
        yield session
        await drop_tables()

# test_something.py
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_something(db):
    async for db in db:
        model = Model(...)
        db.add(model)
        await db.commit()

        foo = await crud(db, model.id)
        assert ...
```

Also, to get rid of that ugly `async for db in db:` you can use from `pytest_asyncio` PyPI package for the fixture:

```py
#conftest.py
import pytest_asyncio

@pytest_asyncio.fixture
async def db() -> AsyncSession:
    async with async_session() as session:
        await create_tables()
        yield session
        await drop_tables()

# test_something.py
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_something(db):
    model = Model(...)
    db.add(model)
    await db.commit()

    foo = await crud(db, model.id)
    assert ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to achieve this by installing only 2 packages in addition to `pytest`:

- [`pytest-postgresql`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-postgresql/) (3rd party plugin) to specify fixtures for psql process and client.
  Read the documentation for usage and examples etc.
- [`pytest-xdist`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/) (official plugin) for distributing tests.
  This simply allows to add `--numprocesses=auto` flag when running pytest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A) I see `pytest-postgresql` uses `psycopg` driver not `asyncpg`, so this would add a difference I'd like to avoid. B) What is the purpose of `pytest-xdist` w/r/t test isolation?

Comment: @dh762 `pytest-postgresql`'s change log [states in 4.0.0](https://github.com/ClearcodeHQ/pytest-postgresql/blob/v5.0.0/CHANGES.rst#400) that _"Xdist running test connecting to already existing postgresql, will now create separate databases for each worker."_

Comment: In other words it seems that it's not `pytest-xdist`'s responsibility to isolate external resources. In our case however `pytest-postgresql` does take care of isolation.